# Solve a congruence with polynomial modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to find a solution for $f(x)$ to the congruence:
$ (x^2-1)f(x) \equiv (x^3+10x) \pmod{x^6+x^5+x+1}$ in $Z_{11}[x]$.

I've tried thinking about this problem in $Z_{11}[x]_{x^6+x^5+x+1}$, where I would just have to find some polynomial $f(x)$ s.t $(x^2-1)f(x) \equiv (x^3+10x)$ in the system. My approach was to just take $x^3+10x$ and mod out by $x^6+x^5+x+1$. But $x^3+10x$ is already simplified in the system so perhaps I need to first multiply it by some polynomial and then mod out. I tried this but I struggled to see how I could obtain a multiple of $x^2-1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a congruence like
\begin{eqnarray*}
2y \equiv 3 \pmod{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is reasonably easy to see that this that $2$ is a zero divisor, Indeed multiply both sides by $3$.

In your case ... multiply by $x^5+1$ & see what happens ?

Comment: I didn't really find any results...I multiplied by $x^5 +1$ on both sides, then divided the right side by the modulus and got a remainder that was not divisible by $x^2-1$...

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(x^5+1)(x^2-1)=(x^5+1)(x+1)(x-1)=\color{red}{(x^6+x^5+x+1)}(x-1).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I understand that this is true. But, if you say $f(x) = x^5+1$, this property holds but I don't think the congruence statement works. What am I missing here?

Comment: That is right and the conclusion is ...  there is no solution.